# BlueJ GUI extension manipulating custom class objects

Tags: bluej

I am exploring BlueJ and trying to learn it's basics. I have created a project with a single class ***MyCounter*** that has an instance variable aCounter with initial value say 10.

I would like to use GUI extension (http://gbluej.slunecnisoustava.eu/?pg=manual&jazyk=en) which simply will show two buttons: Increment and Decrement which will as the names suggest either increment or decrement aCounter value and will display it.

[image]

Steps I have followed so far:

1. Created a project and added a class MyCounter
2. From tools opened Simple GUI Extension and arranged these UI elements, assigned methods to buttons as incrementCounter() etc.

How do I proceed? How do I manipulate Counter through GUI?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have 2 buttons to increment/decrement and then a label with the current number on it. Add action listeners to both of the buttons and then change the value of MyCounter to their respective new values whenever the buttons are clicked then set the label's text to MyCounter again.